# HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush() vs response.redirect false

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

We were notified that the site has following error:

```
Exception Thread was being aborted., ,    at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
```

Upoin investigating we found that the redirection method should be modified.

Current code: `Response.Redirect(URL)`

Should be notified as : `Response.Redirect(URL, false)`

This does solve the problem and is also suggested by Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/en-us

However we also came across the following code:

```
response.Flush();                   
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Reference: http://dotnetplussqlserver.blogspot.in/2014/01/excel-download-responseend-throwing.html

Can someone please help us to clarify which method is better? and what is the significance of one over another?
We just want simple redirection.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

About `Response.Reditect` if you look at the [MSDN Documentation Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) signature of the method is

```
public void Redirect(
    string url,
    bool endResponse
)
```

Where `endResponse` is for

> endResponse
>       Type: System.Boolean
>
> ```
> Indicates whether execution of the current page should terminate.
> ```

So when you say `Response.Reditect(URL, false)` it will redirect to the mentioned `URL` directly without processing the current page further.

Below Quote from Document Page:

> When you use this method in a page handler to terminate a request for
>   one page and start a new request for another page, set endResponse to
>   false and then call the CompleteRequest method. If you specify true
>   for the endResponse parameter, this method calls the End method for
>   the original request, which throws a ThreadAbortException exception
>   when it completes. This exception has a detrimental effect on Web
>   application performance, which is why passing false for the
>   endResponse parameter is recommended.

Comment: @Downvoter, care to leave a comment along with the down vote?

Comment: Thank you for details, but as you can see I am not asking why should we user overloaded redirect method. I am curious to know if it is the best way? or should I use response.Flush();

Comment: @TechTurtle, Which is better is very vogue and opinion based but I haven't seen many people using it rather it's mostly recommended to use `Response.Reditect` method.